# Unable to align text in fixed height div

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to align some text in the center of a div, and I'm not able to do so. I would like to horizontally center it, but vertically I'd like to position it a little higher than the center. The div has a fixed height of 45%. How do I go about doing this?

```
.galf {
width : 100%;
height : 45.3%;
}
.galf a{

}

 <div class = "galf">
 <a>Hello</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .galf {
        width : 100%;
        height : 45.3%;
        text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "galf">
        <a>Hello</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does horizontally align it, but how do I vertically position it?

Comment: add this in your ".galf". {position: relative; top: 25px;}. increase the value accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are just trying to center align the text in div and not center align it vertically and horizontally.

For horizontally center aligning the text, I have created a fiddle with the following solution:-

I hope this helps.

```
HTML Code:-

<div class = "galf">
  <a>Hello</a>
</div>

CSS Code:-
.galf {
  width : 100%;
  height : 45.3%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/y59o0rjc/

For vertical alignment, just a small change to the css :-

```
.galf {
  width : 100%;
  height : 45.3%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align:center;
  display: table;
}

.galf a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flex it will center align your text vertically as well as horizontally

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
}
.galf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45.3%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  background: black
}

.item {
    height: 30%;
    color: black;
    background: red;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.item-container
{
  display:flex;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="galf">
    <a>Hello</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">
    First Div
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Second Div
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Third Div
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now how would I move it higher up so that I can put text under it?

Comment: @Ash Could you explain a little more about the requirement. Where do you want to put text ?

Comment: @Deep flex box will have browser compatibility issue's.No doubt it's a good solution, but it won't work on all browser's.

Comment: @Deep I would like to put a few divs with text under the title "Hello"

Comment: @user3408151 yes thats a good point, here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex we can find the list of all supported browsers.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to align it horizontally:

```
.galf {
width : 100%;
height : 45.3%;
text-align: center;
}

 <div class = "galf">
 <a>Hello</a>
 </div>
```

If you are trying to center vertically

```
.galf {
width : 100%;
height : 45.3%;
line-height: 45.3%;
}

 <div class = "galf">
 <a>Hello</a>
 </div>
```